# Nonintegrable classical dynamical systems and deterministic chaos

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, ergodic-theory, classical-mechanics, chaos

I'm trying to delineate a minimal (and informal) "taxonomy" for classical continuous dynamical systems that could be interested by the phenomenon of "chaos" - unfortunately the sources I've found on the web are rarely compatible...

What I've understood is that if we adopt a strong definition of chaos (i.e. implying nonintegrability, strong mixing, dynamical instability - *e.g.* a K-system) then we have to suppose that there are too nonchaotic but ergodic/mixing systems, nonintegrable nonchaotic nonmixing ones, etc.
If we limit our definition to dynamical instability (or - better - nonzero KS-entropy), we could get too nonmixing chaotic systems.

But there's Nekhoroshev's Theorem that says *all* nonintegrable systems will show at least a region of chaotic motion (Campbell, 1989), and in those regions motion is also strong mixing (Werndl, 2009).

How could those two different viewpoints be made compatible? And where am I wrong?